# Three.js resize window not scaling properly

Tags: three.js, resize

When resizing the window, the shape does not scale properly.[image]

I'm using the following code and according to the documentation, it should be just fine.

```js
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, viewSize;
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
viewSize = 20;
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -aspectRatio * viewSize /  2, aspectRatio * viewSize / 2, viewSize / 2, -viewSize /  2, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.x = 10;
camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.z = -10
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

renderer = window.WebGLRenderingContext ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer() : new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera , renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight);
}

makeShapes();

var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

As seen in the image above, the shapes get dragged out when the window gets bigger and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by rescaling the left, right, top and bottom parameters of the camera proportionally to the window size. Now the object gets its `viewSize` and rescales the size depending on changes made to the window size.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var originalAspect;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

var viewSize = 20;
var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
originalAspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-aspectRatio * viewSize / 2, aspectRatio * viewSize / 2, viewSize / 2, -viewSize / 2, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set( 10, 10, -10 );
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

renderer = window.WebGLRenderingContext ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer() : new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function onWindowResize() {
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var change = originalAspect / aspect;
    var newSize = viewSize * change;
    camera.left = -aspect * newSize / 2;
    camera.right = aspect * newSize  / 2;
    camera.top = newSize / 2;
    camera.bottom = -newSize / 2;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var viewSize = 20;

var camera, scene, renderer;

camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( w / - 2 * viewSize, w / 2 * viewSize, h / 2 * viewSize, h / - 2 * viewSize, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 10, 10, -10 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

renderer = window.WebGLRenderingContext ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer() : new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize() {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
    camera.left = w / - 2 * viewSize;
    camera.right = w / 2 * viewSize;
    camera.top = h / 2 * viewSize;
    camera.bottom = h / - 2 * viewSize;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( w, h );
}
```

Comment: The provided code did unfortunately not solve the problem.

Comment: @Percolator can you share a codepen to see if I can help you with it?